# Is there a way to fix drop down issue in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a list of values in the form of a drop down in one of the cells (Option list) :
[image]

Once you select Option 1 from the drop down VBA will unhide hidden row (25) with left cell and right cell. The problem I am facing is that once option 1 is selected the drop down arrow stays in unhidden row instead of go back to it's place. It is annoying as if left cell box was directly under it it would appear as the drop down arrow belongs to it
[image]

Any Ideas what might cause this and how to fix this ?

Comment: I've tried with a data validation dropdown, with a form dropdown, with an activex dropdown. No problem at all. Can you share your code?

Comment: Make sure the cells in rows 23-25 immediately under your dropdown don't have data validation attached to them.